# OpenFileDialog loop application only after a DB query

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, openfiledialog

I have an difficult situation :

this is my form :

[image]

the first button '...' is a btnAllegato. Code :

```
        private void btnAllegato_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        try
        {

            using (OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog())
            {
                string path = string.Empty;

                openFileDialog1.Title = "Seleziona richiestaIT (PDF)..";
                openFileDialog1.Filter = ("PDF (.pdf)|*.pdf");
                openFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 1;
                openFileDialog1.FileName = "";


                if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {

                    //salva l'intero path
                    path = openFileDialog1.FileName;

                    //nome file + estensione
                    string temp = openFileDialog1.SafeFileName;

                    //elimina l'estensione del file con IgnoreCase -> case Unsensitive
                    temp = Regex.Replace(temp, ".pdf", " ", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

                    //datatime + replace
                    string timenow = System.DateTime.Now.ToString();

                    //replace data da gg//mm/aaaa  ss:mm:hh  ----->  ad   gg-mm-aaaa_ss-mm-hh  
                    timenow = timenow.Replace(":", "-").Replace("/", "-");//.Replace(" ", " ");     

                    _url = @"\\192.168.5.7\dati\SGI\GESTIONE IT\RichiesteIT\" + temp + timenow + ".pdf";

                    System.IO.File.Copy(path, _url);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

after i have a button Inserisci >> (btnInserisci) 
with this button i Create a DB Query to insert data...

```
private void btnInserisci_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if ((_IDRichiedente != -1) && (_data != string.Empty) && (_url != string.Empty))
        {
            MessageBox.Show(_url);
            QueryAssist qa = new QueryAssist();
            string query = "INSERT INTO RICHIESTA_IT(ID_Risorsa, descrizione_richiesta, modulo_pdf, data_richiesta) VALUES('" + _IDRichiedente + "', '" + txtBreveDescrizione.Text + "', '" + _url + "', '" + _data + "');";
            MessageBox.Show(query);

            qa.runQuery(query);

        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Selezionare il richiedente,data o allegato!");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }

}
```

where

```
private int _IDRichiedente = -1;
private string _data = String.Empty;
private string _url = string.Empty;
```

is a fields of class.

QueryAssist is my class that connect, run query and disconnect to Access DB.

code :

```
    class QueryAssist
{
    System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection _OleDBconnection;

    public QueryAssist()
    {
        this._OleDBconnection = null;
    }



    private bool connectionDB()
    {

        string connection = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=\"\\\\192.168.5.7\\dati\\Scambio\\Sviluppo\\Impostazioni temporanea db Censimento\\CensimentoIT.accdb\"";
        try
        {
            _OleDBconnection = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(connection);
            _OleDBconnection.Open();
            return true;

        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            return false;
        }
    }



    private void disconnectDB()
    {
        try
        {
            _OleDBconnection.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);

        }
    }



    public System.Data.DataTable runQuery(string query)
    {
        try
        {
            if (connectionDB())
            {
                System.Data.DataTable dataTable = new System.Data.DataTable();
                System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand sqlQuery = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand(query, _OleDBconnection);
                System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(sqlQuery);
                adapter.Fill(dataTable);
                disconnectDB();
                return dataTable;
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        return null;

    }



    public int countRowsQueryResult(string query)
    {
        try
        {
            if (connectionDB())
            {
                System.Data.DataTable dataTable = new System.Data.DataTable();
                System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand sqlQuery = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand(query, _OleDBconnection);
                System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(sqlQuery);
                adapter.Fill(dataTable);
                disconnectDB();
                return dataTable.Rows.Count;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        return -1;

    }
}
```

At firt time ... The application work good. I selected a file and other data and I click on button 'Inserisci>>' and all working good.

Next step when i want to insert other data ... when i click on '...' button for attachment a file i have the loop OpenFileDialog
[image]

To close, i must kill the process.
I have [STAThread] set on main of the program. 
Connect to NAS isn't a problem ...  I have try in local .. and i have the same problem..

If i click on btn '...' to OpenFileDialg then not click on button 'Inserisci>>'
OpenFileDialog work good for all time ...

But if i click on button 'Inserisci>>' on the next click on button '...' to OpenFileDialog application loop..

Sorry for bad english ..I'm here for clarification

Comment: When exactly program hangs? When you select the file or immediately after you click "..." button?

Comment: Probably is just a typo, (otherwise the code cannot compile) but you are missing a close braces on btnInserisci_Click. More problematic is the code of runQuery. That code cannot insert anything. Insert queries are run through ExecuteNonQuery of an OleDbCommand

Comment: immediately after click button "..." 
The query run good.. Insert into is ok ...

Comment: But did you check if the first record is present in the table RICHIESTA_IT?

Comment: Yes... is present... Repeat... The query run good. 
The problem is the loop application after click on button "..." after btnInserisci_click  run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of the runQuery method with an INSERT statement could be the cause of your problems. To insert a record you should use an OleDbCommand with the ExecuteNonQuery. A Fill method is used to fill a DataTable.

The fact that the record is inserted anyway happens because the underlying command used to fill the DataTable (ExecuteReader) ignores its sql command text and executes what you have passed. However after that the Fill method expects to fill a DataTable and not having a select statement could be potentially the cause of your problems.

I would use a different method when you need to Update/Delete or Insert new data

```
public int runNonQuery(string query)
{
    try
    {
        if (connectionDB())
        {
            OleDbCommand sqlQuery = new OleDbCommand(query, _OleDBconnection);
            int rows = sqlQuery.ExecuteNonQuery();
            disconnectDB();
            return rows;
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        return -1;
    }
}
```

There are other problems in your code and are all connected to the way in which you concatenate together the string to form an sql statement. This is know as the worst practice possible with database code. If you take a bit of your time to investigate how to write a parameterized query you will avoid a lot of future problems.

Comment: ok man.. i will have access to the pc tomorrow. I try this code... but i don't think that is the problem ... because the problem occurs when I open a openfiledialog... ...  not a query(select or other sql command)...
I think that is a problem of resource release or thread... 
 In any case... ExecuteNonQuery is used from INSERT INTO and DELETE command ? For simple query SELECT ? is good a normal string? Or is use to any query with OleDbCommand?

Comment: But you say that if you don't execute the insert you can press the button for the openfiledialog at will. So something is happening there or in the empty table returned by that query. ExecuteNonQuery is used for all the commands that don't return rows. For SELECT you could use ExecuteReader. The DataAdapter infrastructure is used to automate the basic task to fill a memory side datatable and pass back the changes on the DataTable returned by the Fill method. (A lot need to be told here but I can't write a tutorial on use of DataAdapters on a comment)

Comment: ok.. The table returned isn 't empty because (not in query INSERT INTO.but i use same mechanism to other query (SELECT type) and i fill my datagridview and work good...But if isn 't the correct method is right that u suggest, and I go to study this ... ok, tomorrow we will know the truth. : D for now thank you very much... If I have problems with ExecuteReader ,Adapter etc.. I will post new questions. I hope you will help me.
Again thanks.. :)

Comment: i want create a method in queryAssist class that return DataTable for not change all code.. `if(connectionDB()){
                    OleDbCommand sqlQuery = new OleDbCommand(query, _OleDBconnection);
                    OleDbDataReader reader = sqlQuery.ExecuteReader();
                    System.Data.DataTable dataTable = new System.Data.DataTable(); //***code***how to transfer reader to dataTable?

                    reader.Close();
                    return dataTable;
                }`
how return a dataTable after reader query result ?
dataTable.Load(reader) is good way ?!

Comment: Yes, it is a valid alternative to the OleDbDataAdapter logic

Comment: Perfect . Run good. OpenFileDialog now work good! Strange but the error is in SQL read , just as Steve says .. If i haven't openFileDialog I don t even I'd never noticed.. 
Where i  could study - how and when use the OleDbDataAdapter or OleDbDataReader ? Difference ? Why my code is 'broken' etc.. in short, to write logic and good code about db (connection, adpter and reader) ..
Have u a good link ? in msdn API is very confused ..
Thanks so much^10 Steve :)

Comment: It is a long road to know everything about ADO.NET. I think that you could have a better understanding of the ADO.NET infrastructure if you consider the OleDbCommand and OleDbDataReader classes as the building blocks on which the OleDbDataAdapter is built as a convenience to simplify complex work like filling a GridView and updating back the database. So study and understand these two classes. After that looks carefully how to treat disposable objects like the connection and last, but not least USE ALWAYS a parameterized query for your code

Comment: Of course you could avoid knowing the dirty details of ADO.NET if you embrace some kind of Object Relational Mapper like Entity Framework or Micro ORM like Dapper. Ciao